# Apache/PHP confuses dir name and script filename?

Tags: php, apache, lamp, apache-config

Why does an URL like `http://192.168.1.116/wordpress/wp-content/themes/bktf/frameworks/back-end/theme-options/options/fields/font/field_font.js.php?ver=1358535557`

...ends up serving `/wordpress/wp-content/themes/bktf/frameworks/back-end/theme-options.php/options/fields/font/field_font.js.php` (this is also the content of `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']).

...in the context of having both a dir name `theme-options` and a file name `theme-options.php` in the same `back-end` parent dir?

Also, the content of `$_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']` is `/wordpress/wp-content/themes/bktf/frameworks/back-end/theme-options.php`.

Why does Apache or the PHP module automatically add `.php` at the end of a directory name just because there is a scrip with the same as the dir???

***Note:** I am using the default configuration for Apache and PHP for Ubuntu 12LTS server, installed via tasksel and then upgraded to PHP 5.4 with the https://launchpad.net/~ondrej/+archive/php5 PPA, with all the configuration files mostly identical with the defaults/examples - it's a basic LAMP server meant to run in a VM for dev purposes.*

Answer (score 1):

`PHP_SELF` refers to the file being run on the server, not the current url. Read the PHP $_SERVER manual for more info: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Try `$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']` instead. That will give you the query string at the end.

Comment: I know that! That's the point actually, the file being run on the server, $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] has `.../theme-options.php/...` in itr's path while the URL has `.../theme-options/...`. The server just adds a ".php" tot a dir name in the URL, just because there is a script with the same name as the dir! And my only reaction to this isL WhyTF?!

Comment: Is the script working? Or is this causing it to fail? I know wordpress has htaccess rules for dealing with files vs. directories. That is probably where the redirect is happening.

Comment: nope, there's no .htaccess so it doesn't seem to be a redirection problem... the only related thing I found after some googleing is http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/DirectoryAsScript but it doesn't seem to apply for my proble...

Comment: Hrm... usually wordpress generates an htaccess file, is it hidden by any chance? (files beginning with a . are normally hidden by default)

Comment: no, no .htaccess file... but I figured out what was happening... sorry for the "complicated" way of describing the problem in the question

Answer (score 0):

`PHP_SELF` = The filename of the currently executing script, relative to the document root.
`SCRIPT_NAME` = The current script's path.

Comment: see comment to Eric's answer... maybe I phrased the question a bit awkwardly, but my problem is not about the $_SERVER vars, it's about the server serving a script with GET arguments intead of following along the directories in the URL...

Answer (score 0):

OK, the my question was a bit confusing, so I can understand why everyone answered a different question then the one I asked.

Anyway, what was happening in my case was that *there was no `theme-options` dir* (renamed it and forgot) and Apache translated requests like `/[...]/theme-options/[...]` to `/[...]/theme-options.php/[...]` because there was a `theme-options.php` *script*.

I still don't know why an Ubuntu LAMP setup with all the default config does this weird path juggling, but I solved my immediate problem.

Answer (score 0):

Apache translates requests to certain file with extension because of enabled MultiViews option: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_negotiation.html#multiviews